# wxPython threading wxGauge

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I'm trying to learn about threading with wxPython, so I tried to make this simple example work, but it seems that the progress bar updates happen after the "long process" is done. Could anyone tell me why this is not working ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub


class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="wxGauge")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range=10)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="Start process")
        self.sizer.Add(self.gauge)
        self.sizer.Add(self.btn)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        pub.subscribe(self.update, "update")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        self.Show()

    def update(self, msg):
        self.gauge.SetValue(msg.data)

    def OnClick(self, evt):
        for i in range(10):
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "update", i + 1)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the usage of "CallAfter". If call "sendMessage" in this way, it is actually called after the event handler finished.

You can try it in this way:

```
for i in range(10):
    pub.sendMessage("update", i+1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT:**

put this "sendMessage" out of the event handler.

```
    import time
    import wx
    from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub

    class Window(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="wxGauge")
            self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range=10)
            self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="Start process")
            self.sizer.Add(self.gauge)
            self.sizer.Add(self.btn)
            self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
            pub.subscribe(self.update, "update")
            self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)

            self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.TimerHandler)
            self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
            self.gaugeIndex = 0
            self.Show()

        def TimerHandler(self, event):
            self.gaugeIndex += 1
            pub.sendMessage("update", self.gaugeIndex)
            if self.gaugeIndex == 10:
                self.timer.Stop()

        def update(self, msg):
            self.gauge.SetValue(msg.data)

        def OnClick(self, evt):
            self.timer.Start(1000)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        Window()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That did not work either, the GUI freezes for 10s then the gauge is filled.

Comment: Maybe the **sleep** freeze the event handler then freeze the gui, though it works with my wxpython 2.8  But I believe it is better to put the timer thing out of the event handler. New solution attached.